# Split_on_title() and preg_replace() on a data pulled from another website with file_get_contents()

Tags: php

I've pulled data from another website using file_get_contents().

This is the part of source code:

```
<font style="font-size:10px;color:#123333;font-weight:BOLD;">1,22 €</font>
```

I used split_on_title function to pull 1,22 € from the string:

```
$split_on_title = preg_split("<font style=\"font-size:10px;color:#123333;font-weight:BOLD;\">", $source);
$split_on_endtitle = preg_split("</font>", $split_on_title[1]);
$title = $split_on_endtitle[0];
```

And when I echo $title, firefox returns:

```
>1,22 â‚¬<
```

And i used preg_replace on the string:

```
preg_replace('> â‚¬<', '', $title);
```

Then, php shows this error: Warning: preg_replace(): No ending delimiter '>' found in....

How can i pull the clean value of 1,22 €? At least only 1,22.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Understood that it is difficult with the data i gave. I will write a bigger data;

```
<tr>
    <td width="80" align="left" valign="top">
        <b> Price:</b>
    </td>
    <td align="left"  valign="top">
        <font style="font-size:10px;color:#123333;font-weight:BOLD;">1,22 €</font>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I need help to pull 1,22 € from this source.

Answer (score 1):

Please add required support for UTF-8 in the `<head>` section of your html page

`<meta charset="UTF-8" />`

It is missing, therefore euro sign is not rendered properly

More details on how to put in this and other meta tags:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp

Comment: good advice but the output is >1,22 €< now (sorry i wrote another value in previous comment)

Comment: regarding preg_match fix I think @slapyo did it correctly in his answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `preg_match` and grab everything between the font tag?

```
$re = "/<font.*>(.*)<\\/font>/i"; 
$str = "<font style=\"font-size:10px;color:#123333;font-weight:BOLD;\">1,22 €</font>"; 

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Here's how the pattern breaks down.

```
<font matches the characters <font literally (case insensitive)
.* matches any character (except newline)
Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
> matches the characters > literally
1st Capturing group (.*)
.* matches any character (except newline)
Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
< matches the characters < literally
\/ matches the character / literally
font> matches the characters font> literally (case insensitive)
i modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])
```

Comment: I tried it with hard coding(codes you wrote) and encountered this error:Notice: Array to string conversion in...  What should i do with $matches

Comment: @OzanAtmar output it like `echo $matches[1];`

Comment: @pavlovich thanks ... I updated the example to reflect how to output the value.

Comment: Actually it works when you write that string in your $str variable. But this is a page full of html tags and the previous tag is "<td align="left"  valign="top">". Which repeats several times in code. So it is impossible (or i don't know) to pull "<font style=\"font-size:10px;color:#123333;font-weight:BOLD;\">1,22 €</font>" from the source code with preg_split().

Comment: If this is the only place that has this specific font tag with style, then you can do this `$re = "/.*<font.*>(.*)<\\/font>.*/is";`. But that's getting to a not very optimal way of doing this without knowing more information.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @pavlovich gave me an output of >1,22 €<.
And i used;

```
$title = ltrim($title, '>'); 
$title = rtrim($title, '<');
```

to remove the tags.

I know this is not the right way to do it. But solved my problem.